# How do I know what plugin Firefox wants from me?

Tags: firefox

I went to a web page, and it displayed the following message:

[image: A plugin is needed to display this content]

That's all it says. "A plugin is needed to display this content." Nothing else. How am I supposed to know what plugin it needs?

Unfortunately, this is a work critical page, otherwise I would just abandon the site.

Comment: What's the link?

Comment: What does it say in the html if you right click the box (or mark around it and right click) and choose `Inspect Element (Q)` ?